# NSString separation-iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have following strings. But I need to separate them by this "jsonp1343930692" and assign them `NSString` again. How could I that? I could able to separate them to `NSArray` but I don't know how to separate to `NSString`.

```
jsonp1343930692("snapshot":[{"timestamp":1349143800,"data":[{"label_id":10,"lat":29.7161,"lng":-95.3906,"attr":{"ozone_level":37,"exp":"IN","gridpoint":"29.72:-95.39"}},{"label_id":10,"lat":30.168456,"lng":-95.50448}]}]})
jsonp1343930692("snapshot":[{"timestamp":1349144700,"data":[{"label_id":10,"lat":29.7161,"lng":-95.3906,"attr":{"ozone_level":37,"exp":"IN","gridpoint":"29.72:-95.39"}},{"label_id":10,"lat":30.168456,"lng":-95.50448,"attr":{"ozone_level":57,"exp":"IN","gridpoint":"30.17:-95.5"}},{"label_id":10,"lat":29.036944,"lng":-95.438333}]}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsonp1343930692` prefix in your string is odd: I don't know where you string come from, but it really seems to be some JSON string with this strange prefix that has no reason to be there. The best shot here is probably to check if it is normal to have this prefix, for example if you get this string from a WebService it is probably the WebService fault to return this odd prefix.

Anyway, if you want to remove the `jsonp1343930692` prefix of your string, you have multiple options:

- Check that the prefix is existant, and if so, remove the right number of characters from the original string:

  ```
  NSString* str = ... // your string with the "jsonp1343930692" prefix
  static NSString* kStringToRemove = @"jsonp1343930692";
  if ([str hasPrefix:kStringToRemove])
  {
    // rebuilt a string by only using the substring after the prefix
    str = [str substringFromIndex:kStringToRemove.length];
  }
  ```
- Split your string in multiple parts, using the `jsonp1343930692` string as a separator

  ```
  NSString* str = ... // your string with the "jsonp1343930692" prefix
  static NSString* kStringToRemove = @"jsonp1343930692";
  NSArray* parts = [str componentsSeparatedByString:kStringToRemove];
  str = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@""];
  ```
- Replace every occurrences of `jsonp1343930692` by the empty string.

  ```
  NSString* str = ... // your string with the "jsonp1343930692" prefix
  static NSString* kStringToRemove = @"jsonp1343930692";
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:kStringToRemove withString:@""];
  ```

So in short you have many possibilities depending on what exactly you want to do :)

Of course, once you have removed your strange `jsonp1343930692` prefix, you can deserialize your JSON string to obtain a JSON object (either using some third-party lib like `SBJSON` or using `NSJSONSerializer` on iOS5 and later, etc)

Comment: Hello Ali, I am glad to have your reply in detail. My question is how to separate NSString that represents different time stamps. My aim is actually first loading data, then parsing each different JSON timestamp data and then displaying on screen. That is I first collected all data then show it.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly your comment and question, but you should have everything using the componentsSeparatedByString that gives you an array of strings representing each JSON fragment between your `jsonp1343930692` strange separator. Simply iterate then on this array and process each string using your JSON parser (`SBJSON`) then to retrieve the timestamp from it.

Comment: Hello Ali, sorry for bothering you again. I would like to cache the JSON data first then would like to display them on the screen. What method you would recommend. I dont feel so much comfortable at that point, any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Bu arada cok tessekkur ederim.

Comment: Simply store the data in some instance variable and display it when you need. This specific part (cache the JSON data, display them on screen) is a separate question that is worth a dedicated thread: you should open a new question on some forum (or on SO, but I'm not sure that SO is the place for such specific question which basically will need some extended explanations about how to structure and architecture your code and the basics in POO and MVC) for that, as it is not related to your original request (splitting a string into separate parts). iyi şanslar

Comment: I know that is different question not exactly related to my original post. I just want to give try to see whether or not I could get answer without creating new question on SO. Thanks a lot Ali, appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to turn this into a Cocoa collection that you can deal with.

Comment: I am using SBJSON, but I could not able to achieve to separate this string into two strings?